# Recovering from OOM on DirectByteBuffer allocation on a WebFlux Web Server

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I'm not sure if this makes sense so please comment if I need to provide more info:

My webserver is used to upload files (receives files as Multipart/form-data and uploads them to another service). Using WebFlux, the controller defines the argument as a `@RequestPart(name = "payload") final Part payload` which wraps the header and Flux.

Reactor / Netty uses DirectByteBuffers to accomodate the payload. If the request handler cannot get enough direct memory to handle the request, it's gonna fail on an OOM and return 500. So this is normal / expected.

However, what's supposed to happen after?

I'm running load tests by sending multiple requests at the same time (either lots of requests with small files or less requests with bigger files). Once I get the first 500 due to an OOM, the system becomes unstable. Some requests will go through, and other fails with OOM (even requests with very small payload can fail).
This behaviour leds me to believe the allocated Pooled buffers are not shared between IO Channels? However this seems weird, it makes the system very easy to DDOS?

From the tests I did, I get the same behaviour using *unpooled* databuffers, although for a different reason. I do see the memory being unallocated when doing `jcmd <PID> VM.native_memory` but they aren't released to the OS according to metrics & htop. For instance, the reserved memory shown by jcmd goes back down but htop still reports the previous-high amount and it eventually OOM.

So Question :
Is that totally expected or am I missing a config value somewhere?

Setup :
Spring-boot 2.5.5 on openjdk11:jdk-11.0.10_9
Netty config :
`-Dio.netty.allocator.type=pooled -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=paranoid -Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=262144 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=0`

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? I am facing similar issue. Please provide your JVM args .. I would like to get some hint